# Program faster when compiled with -gdwarf-2

Tags: performance, gcc, dwarf

I have a program that does some heavy calculations in a single thread. There is a debug and release build, both with identical command line parameters, except that debug version gets -gdwarf-2. The funny thing is that the version with debug symbols runs around 10% faster than the version without debug symbols.

I inspected the files in both versions and there is nothing that would suggest any differences. All the sections (text, bss, data) are roughly the same size. The assembler generated in both mode looks similar, except for the end. The release version finishes with something like:

```
num_of_entries:
    .quad   10000
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .weakref    _ZL28__gthrw___pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE,__pthread_key_create
    .hidden DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
    .weak   DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
    .section    .data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0,"awG",@progbits,DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0,comdat
    .align 8
    .type   DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0, @object
    .size   DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0, 8
DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0:
    .quad   __gxx_personality_v0
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Whereas the debug version has something like:

```
num_of_entries:
    .quad   10000
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .weakref    _ZL28__gthrw___pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE,__pthread_key_create
    .text
.Letext0:
    .section    .text.unlikely
.Letext_cold0:
    .file 29 "/common/pkgs/gcc/4.9.4/include/c++/4.9.4/type_traits"
    .file 30 "/common/pkgs/gcc/4.9.4/include/c++/4.9.4/bits/cpp_type_traits.h"
...
    .file 104 "/common/pkgs/gcc/4.9.4/include/c++/4.9.4/cxxabi.h"
    .section    .debug_info,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_info0:
    .long   0x59e75
    .value  0x2
    .long   .Ldebug_abbrev0
    .byte   0x8
    .uleb128 0x1
    .long   .LASF6801
    .byte   0x4
    .long   .LASF6802
    .long   .LASF6803
    .long   .Ldebug_ranges0+0x75a0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .long   .Ldebug_line0
    .uleb128 0x2
    .string "std"
    .byte   0x36
    .byte   0
```

I am using GCC 4.9. Can someone please give me a hint or advise me what to do?

Update:
perf stat shows some interesing numbers:

for version with debug symbols:

```
    70,953,691      cache-references
    11,332,829      cache-misses              #   15.972 % of all cache refs
26,489,515,232      cycles
60,272,811,599      instructions              #    2.28  insns per cycle
13,027,834,737      branches
        64,798      faults
             1      migrations
            19      context-switches

   7.181574550 seconds time elapsed
```

for version without debug symbols:

```
    70,256,938      cache-references
    11,960,752      cache-misses              #   17.024 % of all cache refs
27,858,492,922      cycles
59,522,994,867      instructions              #    2.14  insns per cycle
12,779,462,973      branches
        65,212      faults
             1      migrations
            19      context-switches

   7.550653346 seconds time elapsed
```

It seems there is a larger cache miss rate on the release version, even though everything should work the same.

Comment: What's your target architecture?

Comment: x86-64 is the target architecture

Comment: Windows? MacOS? … Android? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: linux is the target arch

Comment: It is impossible to tell anything definite without seeing any code. None of the assembly has any relevance.

Comment: Is assembly code equivalent as well (i.e. output of `objdump -d`, after filtering out offsets)?